# get all control from multiple form in csharp

Tags: c#, winforms

I want to get all the control from multiple form (Main, Two and Three) and
compare if the control tag equals the variable str_name and if true write the 
value of str_value in c.Text.

**the code:**

```
private static Form[] getformular()
{
    Main main = new Main();
    Two f2 = new Two();
    Three f3 = new Three();
    Form[] form = { main, f2, f3};
    return form;
}

private void initcontrol()
{
    String str_name = "name";
    String str_value = "value";
    foreach(Form f in getformular())
    {
        foreach (Control c in f.Controls)
        {
            if (f != null && c = null)
            {
                if (c.Tag.Equals(str_name))
                {
                   c.Text = str_value;
                }
            }
        }
    }
 }
```

Could please someone help me?

Comment: I highly recommend taking a closer look at databinding, so you don't need to reinvent the wheel for this purpose.

Comment: Can you please explain why are you doing this and why you can't just name your TextBox like `nameTextBox` and get it directly?

Comment: Better yet, if you want default values in each textbox, put it there in designer.

Comment: @Sergey Berezovskiy: I need to set the text of the control when I change the language of the program...

Comment: @funk is that text available at compile time? Are you setting text of one particular control, or you use this approach for whole application?

Comment: @Sergey Berezovskiy: I have the values in a XML file. When I choose a language then should change the text of the control.

Comment: `if (f != null && c = null)` shouldn't that be `if (f != null && c != null)`. Not that the null checks are doing anything useful there.

Answer (score 0):

First, as stated by @JonB some of conditional checking (`if`s logic) in your current code seems off.

Second, looping through `Form.Controls` will only bring you all controls placed directly in the Form. For example if you have tab control (or any other container control) placed in form, and you have a textbox inside that tab control, you'll get only the tab control and couldn't find the textbox by looping through `Form.Controls`. You can solve that with recursive method as demonstrated below.

```
private void initcontrol()
{
    String str_name = "name";
    String str_value = "value";
    var result = false;
    foreach(Form f in getformular())
    {
        //if you want to check if f null, it should be here.
        if(f != null) result = setControlText(f, str_name, str_value);
    }
    if(!result) MessageBox.Show("Control not found");
}

private bool setControlText(Control control, string str_name, string str_value)
{
    var isSuccess = false;
    foreach (Control c in control.Controls)
    {
        //if c is not null
        if (c != null)
        {
            //check c's Tag, if not null and matched str_name set the text
            if (c.Tag != null && c.Tag.Equals(str_name))
            {
                c.Text = str_value;
                isSuccess = true;
            }
            //else, search in c.Controls
            else isSuccess = setControlText(c, str_name, str_value);

            //if control already found and set, exit the method now
            if (isSuccess) return true;
        }
    }
    return isSuccess;
}
```